# Why is this derivation of the unit step function in the Z-domain valid?

Tags: control-theory

[This source](http://www.ele.uri.edu/Courses/ele541/tutorials/ztransforms/commonfunctions.html) states that the unit step function in the Z-domain is 
$\frac{z}{z-1}$. However, in its derivation it states $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} z^{-k} = \frac{z}{z-1}$.

But doesn't that last relation only hold true for $z>1$? I don't see how that condition is met. I know that the poles have to be in the unit circle for the system to be stable, but I don't see if and how that connects to the condition above.

What am I missing?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. For $|z| > 1$ we have $\sum_k {1 \over z^k} = {1 \over 1-{1 \over z}}$ which is what you have above. What system are you referring to regarding stability?

Comment: Yes, but |z|>1 doesn't generally hold in the Z-domain, so why can you say $\frac{z}{z-1}$ is the unit step function for any complex z? I don't understand your stability question. This is just a general question, I don't have a specific system in mind, but the goal is a stable system.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, like the Laplace transform, the Z transform is usually only defined on some domain, typically of the form $|z| > R$ for the ${1 \over z}$ version of the transform. You haven't mentioned any system, so it is hard to answer your questions. An input is just an input, there is no stability issue associated with it.

Comment: Never in my EE control theory lectures have I come across domain limitations on the P or Z domain. The only limitations I know about are on pole positions regarding stability. The only thing I can say about the systems we analyze is that they are LTI.

Comment: I'm not sure how to respond. For example, with the Laplace transform, the transform of a unit step is only defined (via the transform) for $\operatorname{re} s > 0$. It can be represented by the formula $s \mapsto {1 \over s}$ for $s \neq 0$ by analytic continuation. The integral or Laurent series must be convergent.

Comment: I'm guessing that the |z|<1 isn't relevant because we're only looking at k>=0, but I don't see the link.

Comment: Note that the formula ${z \over z-1}$ is also the value of $-\sum_{k=1}^\infty z^k$ for $|z| < 1$. My point is that the connection between the formula and the transform depends on the ROC.

Comment: @RungeKutta That's because kernel transforms are very hard and we do a discourse to engineering students by skipping concepts like analytic continuation and meramorphic functions. The analyticity allows the function definition to be extended to domains that these functions are not defined. Other answers than this is handwaving but it is really a high level subject so you can safely assume that it can be done. Or dig into it :D I'm teaching control theory and this is one of the many reasons that state space methods are much better to analyze.

Comment: @percusse This is the clearest answer I have gotten so far. If you type this out as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @percusse you can go as deep into it as you'd like, but as a reference: my current understanding of the topic of analytic continuation stops after [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sD0NjbwqlYw).

Answer (score 0):

The $z$-transform like the $s$-transform is a tool, and it is important to know what you are analyzing with the tool. Knowing that the output of the tool is $z/(z-1)$ is not sufficient to make conclusions.

In one scenario, you could impulse a linear system and find out that it is the unit step, and you take the z-transform of it, it comes out to be $z/(z-1)$. This is the transfer function of the system

$$
Y(z)/U(z) = z/(z-1),
$$
and now you can conclude that this linear system is unstable.

In another scenario, you could be handed a linear system
$$
Y(z)/U(z) = 0.5z/(z-0.2),
$$
and be asked to find the response to a unit step. So what do you do? You have to first obtain $U(z) = z/(z-1)$, and then substitute it in and so on. Now in this case, it doesn't make sense to say that $U(z)$ is not valid because it is not stable.